# Can't multiply 2 columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue. As you see the following example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[127093342616], 'b':[22853943721]})
data['a*b']= data['a']*data['b']
data
```

- When I multiply 2 numbers: **127093342616** vs **22853943721**, the result = **2904584099459834914136**
- But, when I use DataFrame of pandas and multiply the 2 columns the result = **8445279887435310424**

Can anybody tell me the reason this occurs and a solution?

Comment: Odd behaviour. I think this may have something to do with "long scalars"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using float datatype, you're having integer overflow problems:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[127093342616], 'b':[22853943721]}, dtype=np.float)
data['a*b']= data['a']*data['b']
data
```

Output:

```
              a             b           a*b
0  1.270933e+11  2.285394e+10  2.904584e+21
```

Because pandas use numpy underneath, let's look at [numpy datatypes](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html#data-types).

numpy.int64 - Integer (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)

Answer (score 2):

#### Comprehension

```
data['a*b'] = [a * b for a, b in zip(data.a, data.b)]

data

              a            b                     a*b
0  127093342616  22853943721  2904584099459834914136
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  Feel free to upvote the answer as well.